# NuxtJS if-statement not able to respond to changed value

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

I'm trying to use an if-statement in NuxtJS to decide wether to show an element or not. The value for this if-statement comes from a function that is accessing a Graphql-API.

I do get the correct value, but because the API takes a bit to respond, the if-statement doesn't react to the change in value/fullfilment of the promise.

HTML-Part:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-btn
            v-if="checkPermission('70ff3199-d049-4ff7-8ca7-a4b46ba6e81a')"
            text
            to="/schemaEditor"
        >
            Schema Editor
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
            v-if="checkPermission2"
            text
            to="/frontEnd"
        >
            Front End
        </v-btn>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javescript-Part:

```
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        checkPermission (permissionId) {
            this.$apollo.query({
                variables: {
                    permissionId
                },

                query: gql`
                    query (
                        $permissionId: String
                    ) {
                        checkPerimssionId (
                            permissionId: $permissionId
                        )
                    }
                `
            }).then((data) => {
                return data.data.checkPerimssionId
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log({ error })
                return false
            })
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I did try the same with computed properties, by putting the functioncall inside the coputed property, but with the same result. For some reason the promise from the function accessing the API doesn't get resolved, even though I see that I get the correct result.

Am I understanding something wrong about if-statements, or is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Hi, what do you see in your Vue devtools? Do you have the proper state there? Also, everything is good in your network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You have an asynchronous call that you should wait until it's resolved to check it's value.

What i suggest is to use [Nuxt fetch hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch/) to do your call, and use `$fetchState.pending` to check loading state.
Something like that :

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="$fetchState.pending"> Loading ...</div>
    <div v-else>
        <v-btn
            v-if="checkPermissionValue"
            text
            to="/schemaEditor"
        >
            Schema Editor
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
            v-if="checkPermission2"
            text
            to="/frontEnd"
        >
            Front End
        </v-btn>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript part :

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        checkPermissionValue: false,
      };
    },
    async fetch() {
      this.checkPermissionValue = await this.checkPermission(
        "70ff3199-d049-4ff7-8ca7-a4b46ba6e81a"
      );
    },
    methods: {
      async checkPermission(permissionId) {
        await this.$apollo
          .query({
            variables: {
              permissionId,
            },

            query: gql`
              query ($permissionId: String) {
                checkPerimssionId(permissionId: $permissionId)
              }
            `,
          })
          .then((data) => {
            return data.data.checkPerimssionId;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log({ error });
            return false;
          });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Apollo also gives some helpers like `pending` AFAIR.